# Facebook API auto post on wall

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk

I have a requirement where I need to publish some updates on users wall automatically. Users have already  granted permission for `publish_actions` and I have USER IDs stored in DB. Now by using some cron jobs, I want to update those users wall either with some photos or with some links.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'XXX';
    $config['secret'] = 'XXX';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $session = $facebook->getUser();
    $result = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'users.setStatus',
        'status' => 'Hello World',
        'uid' => '123', /// user_id 
        'session' => $session,
            ));
?>
```

This works fine, but it is not sharing links as feed or photos. Using JS Sdk it was possible but it seems that FB has discontinued that since 6 Feb 2013.

Is there any correct way to do this?

Comment: which version of `PHP-SDK` are you using? `users.setStatus` is deprecated

Comment: I found that code in some other questions. The SDK is old, so don't have exact version for it

Answer (score 0):

Use [Facebook 3.0 PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk), `$facebook->api()` first argument requires an endpoint `/me/feed`, `/me/photos` while the second is the method `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` and the third is an `array` of parameters you want to send along with the call so try:

```
$session = $facebook->getUser();
if ($session) {

      $p = array( 'message'      => 'Hello World',
                  'access_token' => 'CAAA...' ); // a valid access token with publish_action permission
      $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $p);

} else { 

      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      header('Location:'. $loginUrl);

}
```

Comment: is it possible using the latest SDK or javascript SDK?

Comment: Why not? but I prefer the v3.0 because it's easier to implement

Comment: Also I tried your code, but as I said I have user ID's, no session of users. Status updates work perfectly but for photos, its throwing me error `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.`. I tried this way: `$result = $facebook->api('/123456/photos', 'POST', $p);`

Comment: I didn't add `access_token` because your code has `getUser()` which indicates that the user is authorized via oAuth dialog, anyways I will update the answer

Comment: some important additional info (may be a good idea to add it to the answer): the message parameter MUST be 100% user generated. you are not allowed to put in anything you want, and you cannot prefill it either. you have to present an EMPTY textfield to the user where he can put in his own message.